# What is the best package to use SVG inline in NuxtJS?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I find the best package to use SVG inline in NuxtJS, which can be rendered HTML. I use this package: [svg-inline-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader). It's display SVG HTML but it must have insert all SVG in document to use: View this [example](https://github.com/osudio-erik/svg-icons/blob/master/pages/index.vue). It must have insert `<svg v-html="require('~/assets/sprite.svg')"></svg>` to render SVG.

Do you guys know what package is better to make SVG inline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `vue-svg-loader`.

Install it with either `npm` or `yarn`:

```
npm install --save-dev vue-svg-loader
yarn add --dev vue-svg-loader
```

Then configure your webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  loader: 'vue-svg-loader'
}
```

*Edit:* or with `vue-cli-3.*` (in your `vue.config.js`):

```
chainWebpack: config => {
  const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')

  svgRule.uses.clear()
  svgRule
    .use('vue-svg-loader')
    .loader('vue-svg-loader')
    .options({
      svgo: false
    })
}
```

And finally a usage example in your `.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="...">
      <SomeIcon class="icon" />
      Some page
    </a>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
import SomeIcon from './assets/some-icon.svg'

export default {
  name: 'menu',
  components: { SomeIcon }
}
</script>
```

See more: [docs](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader).

Comment: There is now a nuxt community plugin to do that: https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-module